# Compare 2 Objects of Generic Class Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a homework and I have to compare 2 object's by one of their properties, but since I'm working with generic types on my linked list where I have to store the objects I can't really reach the object's certain property (I'm using an interface, and all of the classes implement that interface)
So I have got a major interface, and some classes (i.e. class1, class2) that inherit the interface properties such as Age, or any kind of number that is comparable easily. In Main() I just created a new LinkedList and created some class1, class2 objects. I put them in the ordered list with that SortedListAddElement method, but I'm stuck at the part where it should compare the element's by the int properties. How should I go on from there with this source code? Should I change the first line to: class List : IEnumerable, IComparable, IMajorInterface? Or change something in CompareTo()? Please help!

```
interface IMajorInterface 
{ 
    string Name{ get; } 
    int Age { get; set; } 
}

class List<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    ListElement<T> head;

    public List()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    public void SortedListAddElement(T newValue)
    {
        ListElement<T> new = new ListElement<T>(newValue);
        ListElement<T> p = head;
        ListElement<T> e = null;
        while (p != null /* && this is the part where I should compare the p and new objects by their property, for example the Age property, like: p.Age < new.Age */)
        {
            e = p;
            p = p.Next;
        }
        if (e == null)
        {
            new.Next = head;
            head = new;
        }
        else
        {
            new.Next = p;
            e.Next = new;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (obj is T)
            {
                T obj2 = obj as T;
                return obj.Age.CompareTo(obj2.Age);
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `List<T>` class is supposed to implement the `IComparable<T>` interface? The way `CompareTo` is implemented, you compare `obj` to itself (`obj2` is *the same* as `obj`).

Comment: Also, please take care of proper terminology: A class does not *inherit* anything from an interface, it can only *implement* members of an interface.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will correct that one.

No, I am absolutely not sure. I have no idea how I am supposed to compare 2 objects if I got to use generic list. Our teacher told nothing about sorted linked lists, neither about the comparing stuff if you have generic types.

Comment: I am still not sure I imagine your assignment description correctly: Were you told *you* had to compare the properties of whichever type `T` is yourself? Where is that "major interface" you are referring to? Were you provided with any code for that?

Comment: Yes, I've been told that I have to do the comparing part.

    interface IMajorInterface
    {
        string Name{ get; }
        int Age { get; set; }
    }

I've got a few classes that implement the interface above, so the properties as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options to solve that. Here is one approach. First, make your major interface comparable:

```
interface IMajorInterface : IComparable<IMajorInterface>
{
    string Name{ get; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then constrain your generic type parameter in the list class implementation:

```
class List<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // ... Code omitted for brevity.
}
```

Then implement the `IComparable` interface in your concrete major classes (class1, class2). Maybe it would be advisable to implement a base class for those, implement the interface there and derive the class1 and class2, etc. from that base class. Perhaps it would be even better to drop the `IMajorInterface` altogether and just make an abstract `Major` base class.

Alternatively, as you are only using the list for majors, you could just constrain the generic list parameter to the `IMajorInterface` or `Major` base class itself. That would be the simplest (and least flexible) solution:

```
class List<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IMajorInterface // No need to implement IComparable<T> in any class.
{
    // ... Code omitted for brevity.
}
```

Finally, as another approach, you could provide an `IComparer<T>` to the list on its constructor, just as the `System.Collections.Generic` classes do. Investigate on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx).

I hope it helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

you can implement IComparer.

```
class ageComparer : IComparer<Person>
   {
        public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return x.Age - y.Age;
        }
   }
```

Have a look at this article http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IComparer_2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article at c-sharpcorner that compares generic types:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/compare-2-objects-of-generic-class-type-in-C-Sharp/

Quick code snippet:

```
 static bool Compare<T>(T Object1, T object2)
 {
      //Get the type of the object
      Type type = typeof(T);

      //return false if any of the object is false
      if (Object1 == null || object2 == null)
         return false;

     //Loop through each properties inside class and get values for the property from both the objects and compare
     foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
     {
          if (property.Name != "ExtensionData")
          {
              string Object1Value = string.Empty;
              string Object2Value = string.Empty;
              if (type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(Object1, null) != null)
                    Object1Value = type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(Object1, null).ToString();
              if (type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(object2, null) != null)
                    Object2Value = type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(object2, null).ToString();
              if (Object1Value.Trim() != Object2Value.Trim())
              {
                  return false;
              }
          }
     }
     return true;
 }
```